# Want to clear Big picture about the AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I want to clear big picture about the aws Glue regarding some of the following aspects.

1. How AWS Glue prepare and provision its infrastructure? However it's serverless but how does it manage it?
2. How it's using apache spark and hadoop to solve so many ETL jobs at a time, Almost jobs of hundreds of AWS Glue customers from every region.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Glue uses [EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) underneath. It spawns a new cluster with required number of executors (depending on configured DPU) when a new job starts. However, to improve cold start time they have a buffer of already provisioned EMR clusters for the most common number of DPUs. To manage all this they have a set of automated services that monitor state of each cluster, start a new ones etc.